# Обращаться к ПК центрального филиала через vpn по имени

Tags: dns, vpn, mikrotik

Есть главный офис с микротик, на котором поднят vpn l2tp+Ipsec+OSPF сервер и есть удаленные филиалы, на них тоже микротик, которые соединяются с центральным. VPN работает, но хотелось бы настроить так, чтобы можно было с ПК центрального офиса к ПК на удаленных точках(или наоборот) обращаться по их имени, а не IP адресу. Подскажите возможно ли так настроить и если да то, примерно, как?
DHCP и DNS в центральном офисе раздает отдельный сервер, в филиалах DHCP - микротик.

Comment: а в микротике не пробовали ? "https://192.168.0.1/webfig/#IP:DNS.Static"

Comment: @AlexGlebe в центральном офисе 100+ машин, ip этих машин могут иногда меняться. Прописывать их сопоставление в IP-DNS-Static и следить за их актуальностью наверное не самый лучший вариант, или этот как то по другому работает?

Comment: Указать в DHCP-сервере адрес DNS-сервера вашего центрального офиса не работает?